# How to bring to front the shapefile in R?

Tags: r, overlay, raster, shapefile

I want to overlap the shapefile named "havza" onto the raster data named "gio_ara, but the shapefile file appears behind the raster in the plot, how can I fix this?

[The black line at the back is the shapefile named "havza"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFE56.png)

Here is my code:

```
# Read Havza(region)
havza=readOGR(dsn= "D:\\FIRAT HAVZA", layer= "firat_havza_new")
plot(havza)

# Read Aralik PM DEM
gio_ara = readGDAL("D:\\FIRAT HAVZA\\Giovanni_PM10\\ara_pm")
gio_ara$RASTERVALU = gio_ara$band1
gio_ara$band1 = NULL
spplot(gio_ara, col.regions=bpy.colors(), scales=list(draw=T))

spplot(gio_ara, col.regions=bpy.colors(), main="Aralik PM10",scales=list(draw=T),
       sp.layout=list(havza))
```

I read the data just as written in the code, but the shapefile data always appear behind the raster data.

I want the shapefile data to overlay the raster.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

maybe with this change you can fix your problem

```
# Read Havza (region)
havza <- readOGR(dsn = "D:\\FIRAT HAVZA", layer = "firat_havza_new")
# Read Aralik PM DEM
gio_ara <- readGDAL("D:\\FIRAT HAVZA\\Giovanni_PM10\\ara_pm")
gio_ara$RASTERVALU = gio_ara$band1
gio_ara$band1 = NULL

# Plot the raster
spplot(gio_ara, col.regions = bpy.colors(), main = "Aralik PM10", scales = list(draw = TRUE))

# Overlay the shapefile on top of the raster
spplot(gio_ara, col.regions = bpy.colors(), main = "Aralik PM10", scales = list(draw = TRUE), sp.layout = list(havza), layer = "onTop")
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried as you wrote, but unfortunately, the shapefile still appears in the back.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "rgdal" package that is no longer available on CRAN. A more modern approach would be:

```
library(terra)
havza <- vect("D:/FIRAT HAVZA/firat_havza_new.shp")
gio_ara <- rast("D:/FIRAT HAVZA/Giovanni_PM10/ara_pm")
plot(gio_ara)
lines(havza)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm gonna try this.